# Are Chrome incognito cookies temporarily saved "per session" or "per tab?"

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies, browser

When using Chrome, or any other browser, in incognito mode, are the cookies saved per tab or per session?  When closing an incognito tab, will the cookies remain for the other incognito tabs?  To absolutely clean out the cookies, will the whole session need to be shut down?

Comment: This would take about three seconds to test (longer than it took to post your question, for sure). Open an incognito window. Log into a website like Facebook. Open a new tab in the incognito window. Go to Facebook. Are you logged in?

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are saved per session. So if you are logged into Facebook in one tab, then you open Facebook in another tab, you'll still be logged in. In other words, yes the cookies will remain for the other incognito tabs if you close one. If it were per tab, if you were logged into Facebook in one tab then you open another tab and go to Facebook, you would be prompted to login in that new tab. To absolutely clean out the cookies, the entire incognito session needs to be shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

sharing session information is what browsers do. its for when you are on a website and open a poppup. it would not make much sence if you need to re-login on each single popup.

internet explorer has a nice trick for it.

INTERNET EXPLORER:

When you click File -> New Window (or Ctrl - N, or click the IE short-cut on Start Menu) of IE 8, a new window will be created.  However, this new window will share the same session information with the original window.  In other words, if the original window is logged in to your web mail (e.g. hotmail), you do not need to log in again to your web mail in the newly created window.

When you click File -> New Session, a new session window will be created.  This new window will not use any information from the original window.  In other words, even if the orginal window is logged in to your web mail (e.g. hotmail), you still need to log in again to your web mail in the newly created window.